# Rails update individual attribute not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following scenario:

A user cancels their account, and optionally gives a reason.
The reason is saved, and the user is soft_deleted.

For some reason my code to set the reason doesn't result in any updates being saved.

Here is my code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

    def set_cancellation_reason(reason)
        cancellation_reason = reason
        save!
    end

end
```

What is wrong here that cancellation_reason is not getting persisted?

This is what happens if I run the code from the console:

```
 u = User.first
  User Load (2.0ms)  SELECT "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."deleted_at" IS NULL ORDER BY "users"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
 => #<User id: 1, email: "leebrooks0@gmail.com", encrypted_password: "$2a$15$GQ.WHk.nxlArc668bf3NW.WFJVV.ost3R85PGs6ePYaT...", role_id: nil, reset_password_token: nil, reset_password_sent_at: nil, remember_created_at: nil, sign_in_count: 11, current_sign_in_at: "2014-03-21 12:08:54", last_sign_in_at: "2014-03-21 12:06:31", current_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", last_sign_in_ip: "127.0.0.1", confirmation_token: nil, confirmed_at: "2014-03-21 10:59:27", confirmation_sent_at: nil, unconfirmed_email: nil, failed_attempts: 0, unlock_token: nil, locked_at: nil, cancellation_reason: nil, created_at: "2014-03-21 10:59:27", updated_at: "2014-03-21 12:12:29", deleted_at: nil> 
2.1.1 :008 > u.set_cancellation_reason("hogwash")
   (0.5ms)  BEGIN
   (0.4ms)  COMMIT
 => true
```

Comment: hm seems correct, what is in the log?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might nbe missing something on how it is being called, but I would do the following. I am assuming this is being called from a controller or view.

```
Called by using myuser.set_cancellation_reason("don't like it")

def set_cancellation_reason(reason)
    self.cancellation_reason = reason
    self.save!
end
```

I'm also assuming you set the cancelled flag somewheer else otheriwse you need

```
self.cancel_flag = true
```

Comment: I updated my question to show how I call it from the console (doesn't work there...). Yes I soft delete elsewhere, but that part works, so I left it out to avoid clutter.

Comment: I'd stand by my initial response about putting self before the two lines then.

Answer (score 2):

When doing `cancellation_reason = reason`, it will create a `cancellation_reason` variable instead of calling the dynamic method `cancellation_reason=` defined by Active Record.

`self` is the default receiver but when the expression can be ambiguously considered to be an assignation, the assignation wins.

You can use `self.cancellation_reason = reason` to be sure to pick up the rails method but I prefer doing the following :

```
update_attribute(:cancellation_reason, reason)
```

I think it's more clear, and you don't need an extra line for saving.

Comment: Doh! Creating a local variable.